# ESLint linting my Typescript files correctly

Tags: node.js, typescript, eslint

I have .js files ( src/client/...) and .ts files ( src/server/.. )

I installed the following packages :

**package.json**

```
  "eslint": "^5.11.1",
  "eslint-config-airbnb-base": "^13.1.0",
  "eslint-config-typescript": "^1.1.0",
  "eslint-plugin-import": "^2.14.0",
  "eslint-plugin-typescript": "^0.14.0",
  ....
  "typescript": "^3.0.3",
  "typescript-eslint-parser": "^21.0.2",
```

And I defined the following aslant config in package.json

```
  "eslintConfig": {
    "extends": ["airbnb-base", "eslint:recommended", "typescript"],
    "env": { "es6": true, "browser": true },
    "parserOptions": { "parser": "typescript-eslint-parser" },
    "plugins": ["typescript"],
    "rules": {
      "no-unused-vars": ["error", { "vars": "all", "args": "after-used", "ignoreRestSiblings": false }],
      "no-var": ["off"],
      "one-var": ["off"],
      "prefer-destructuring": ["error", { "object": false, "array": false } ],
      "no-underscore-dangle": ["error", { "allow": ["__blogPostData"] }]
    }
  }
```

Then I set the lint script :

```
 "lint": "eslint src --fix",
```

It's listing correctly all my .js files , but I don't see any warnings/errors in my .ts files ( I doubt they are all well written...)

Am I wrong or missing anything in my eslint setup for typescript  ?

Answer (score -7, accepted):

You should use tslint for TypeScript, not eslint:

```
npm i tslint --save
```

after that, create a tslint.json in your project root (or pick one from the web with the rules you like). Just a link I found on Google: [ts lint setup](https://spin.atomicobject.com/2017/06/05/tslint-linting-setup/)

Comment: thanks a lot @Bronco... going to set it up ... I'll also write 2 scripts :  lint-client ( eslint .js client files and lint-server ( ts lint .ts node server files )

Comment: Solved .. it runs OK

Comment: Please provide a rationale if your answer to "How do I use technology A?" is "Use technology B instead".  However, one shouldn't use tslint because Microsoft has deprecated it in favor of eslint - https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/29288#developer-productivity-tools-and-integration  (granted, this development occurred 6 days *after* the answer was posted)

Answer (score 5):

`parser` is a root-level config item, not a field of `parserOptions`:

```
 "eslintConfig": {
    "parser": "typescript-eslint-parser"
    "parserOptions": { ...options },
    "plugins": ["typescript"]
  }
```

Also, the parser and plugin you are using are deprecated.  The newer/maintained projects are both available at https://github.com/typescript-eslint/typescript-eslint. (Config is the same, just with updated names).  Here is an nice step-by-step walk-through on how to set this up - https://dev.to/robertcoopercode/using-eslint-and-prettier-in-a-typescript-project-53jb

Note that rather than defining your eslint config in `package.json`, you could instead use a  separate`.eslintrc.{js,yaml}`.  One in the root directory would setup your standard rules for JavaScript and another one in `./src/server` could setup the TypeScript parser & plugin only for the relevant directory (but still pick up all your standard root rules).

Comment: some background info on the tslint to eslint move: https://eslint.org/blog/2019/01/future-typescript-eslint